# How to call dynamically a button from parent to a child form using shortcut keys/key down using vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I have a parent form and has toolstrip buttons, how can i call buttons from parent to a child form using shortcut keys like ctrl + Z to a button Undo from parent toolstrip buttons.

thanks.

Comment: Trying to understand the parent / child relationship. Are you using MDI forms?

Answer (score 0):

If the relationship is an MDI parent with a child form, then the user should be able to click on buttons in the parent even while a child form is active.

But if you also want the user to be able to use hot keys, or maybe a button on the child form or what have you, that means you have a function that you want to be able to use from multiple places.

Probably best way to do that (specially for something like Undo) is to put those functions themselves within a global module and call the global function from wherever you need to.

I.E.: If you have already put the code to undo an action into the parent's Undo button, then just move that to a global module and make it a callable method, then make the parent's button call that. And in the child form, make the ctrl+Z keypress call that same thing.

Hope that helps, anyway...